# MySQL simple select query is slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large mysql-table with about 110.000.000 items

The Table Design is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tracksim` (
`tracksimID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`trackID1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`trackID2` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sim` double NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`tracksimID`),
UNIQUE KEY `TrackID1` (`trackID1`,`trackID2`),
KEY `sim` (`sim`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I want to query a normal query:

```
SELECT trackID1, trackID2 FROM `tracksim` 
WHERE sim > 0.5 AND 
      (`trackID1` = 168123 OR `trackID2`= 168123)
ORDER BY sim DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

The Explain statement gives me:

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tracksim | range | TrackID1,sim  | sim  | 8       | NULL | 19980582 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

The query seems to be very slow(about 185 seconds), but i don't know if it is only because of the amount of items in the table. Do you have a tip how I can speedup the query or the table-lookup?

Comment: How many matches do you get? I suspect it is the `ORDER BY sim DESC` that is taking the most time.

Comment: Well, what's the *purpose* of the table - and of `sim`, `track1` and `track2`? Without this, nobody can tell whether the table design is efficient or not...

Comment: The purpose of the table is to hold information about the similarity of different tracks. In my case i have about 2 million songs (here i used a subset) and calculate a similarity score. This score has a range from -1 to +1 and i'm only save the ones which are larger than 0. To not save NxN items i only save NxN/2 tracks because it is bidirectional. In my case the trackID2 is always smaller than trackID1. To calculate in the next step i need the top-k of the similarest tracks.

Comment: can partitioning the table be an option ? absolutely no experience with that level of data, but i have managed to remarkably improve query results with table partitioning.

Comment: @KishorKundan , i think because of the distribution of the data I don't think this will work. Even if i have different tables i have to lookup in every table for the values. Or i save all the NxN items which are larger than 0. But this may be a ton of data

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the query, you just got a lot of results back. Use `SET PROFILING = 1; SELECT.. <your query>; SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1`. Post the output of that so we can see which layer is taking up the most time.

Comment: @simon : i am not sure if you understood what i said, table partioning will create logical partions of your existing table either based on hash, range or key. This breaks down the look up information. give it a visit http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly I agree with Drap, but the following variation of the query might be even more efficient, especially for larger LIMIT:

```
SELECT TS2.*
FROM (
  SELECT tracksimID, sim
  FROM tracksim
  WHERE trackID1 = 168123
    AND sim > 0.5
  UNION
  SELECT trackSimID, sim
  FROM tracksim
  WHERE trackid2 = 168123
    AND ts.sim > 0.5
  ORDER BY sim DESC
  LIMIT 0, 100
) as PreQuery
JOIN TrackSim TS2 USING (TrackSimID);
```

Requires `(trackID1, sim)` and `(trackID2, sim)` indexes.

Comment: You are right, the query is a little bit faster than the query by Drap. Thank you (and Drap) very much.

Comment: So i tested it and it is about 10 seconds per query. I've tried to speed id up, and i have a solution to run it a little bit faster. In the PreQuery it helps to limit the resultset of each query to 100 elements, so the resultset of each query is at max 100 and the union is a bit faster. In addition the last JOIN with tracksim is not required if you add the trackID2 in the first select of the PreQuery and trackID1 in the second select of PreQuery. It helped me to speed up the whole query so i'm about 1 second per query. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

With 110 million records, I can't imagine there are many entries with the track ID in question.  I would have indexes such as

```
(trackID1, sim )
(trackID2, sim )
(tracksimID, sim)
```

and do a PREQUERY via union and join against that result

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
      TS2.*
   from
      ( select ts.tracksimID
           from tracksim ts
           where ts.trackID1 = 168123
             and ts.sim > 0.5
        UNION
        select ts.trackSimID
           from tracksim ts
           where ts.trackid2 = 168123
             and ts.sim > 0.5 
      ) PreQuery
      JOIN TrackSim TS2
         on PreQuery.TrackSimID = TS2.TrackSimID
   order by
      TS2.SIM DESC
   LIMIT 0, 100
```

Comment: The idea looks good, but what is that `distinct` for? TracksimID is a primary key anyway and `union` without `all` is distinct by default.

Comment: @piotrm, distinct was accidental.  I typed what I was thinking forgetting about the union to get the second half.  Yes, UNION prevents duplicates.  Thanks for spotting it and I'll adjust it.

Comment: Thanks, this query was faster than my approach. Helped me to speed up :)

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering your query so you don't return the full table.  Alternatively you could try applying an index to the table on one of the track ID's, for example:

```
CREATE INDEX TRACK_INDEX
ON tracksim (trackID1)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm

Comment: This is assuming that `trackID1` is *supposed* to be unique; also, using your new index will preclude using the `sim` index.

Comment: The trackID1 is not unique, because the similarity between every track is calculated and if(trackID1>trackID2 && sim>0) saved.

Comment: @simon You could still use the index I have provided if trackID1 is not unique :)