# Missing Mysql-Opimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, status

I have precomputet some similarities (about 70 million) and want to find the similarities from one track to all other tracks. I only need the top-100-tracks that have the highest similarities. For my calculations i do this query about 15'000 times with different tracks as input. After a boot of the machine one calculation needs over 600 seconds for all 15k queries. After several runs, mysql has - i think - cached the indices so the complete run needs about 15 seconds. My only worries are: i have a very hight "Handler_read_rnd_nextDokumentation" value.

I have a MySQL table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `similarity` (
  `similarityID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `trackID1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `trackID2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tracksim` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `timesim` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `tagsim` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `simsum` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`similarityID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `trackID1` (`trackID1`,`trackID2`),
  KEY `trackID1sum` (`trackID1`,`simsum`),
  KEY `trackID2sum` (`trackID2`,`simsum`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to do very much queries on this. The queries look like this:

```
// simsum is a sum over tracksim, timesim, tagsim
(
     SELECT similarityID, trackID2, tracksim, timesim, tagsim, simsum
     FROM similarity
     WHERE trackID1 = 512
     ORDER BY simsum DESC
     LIMIT 0,100
 )
 UNION
(
     SELECT similarityID, trackID1, tracksim, timesim, tagsim, simsum
     FROM similarity
     WHERE trackID2 = 512
     ORDER BY simsum DESC
     LIMIT 0,100
 )
 ORDER BY simsum DESC
 LIMIT 0,100
```

The query is quite fast and under 0.1 sec ([previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927272/mysql-simple-select-query-is-slow/9930271#9930271)) but i'm worried about the very huge number in the status page. I thought i have set every index that i'm using in the query.

```
Handler_read_rndDokumentation   88,0 M
Handler_read_rnd_nextDokumentation  20,0 G
```

Is there anything "wrong"? Could i get the query even faster? Do i have to worry about the 20G ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The first thing which is obviously wrong here is that you seem to be calculating a directional relationship between tuples - if f(a,b)===f(b,a) then you could simplify your system a lot by swapping around track1 and track2 where track1 is greater than track2 but retaining the existing primary key (and ignore collisions).

You're only halving the amount of data - so it won't be a huge performance increase.

There may be further scope for improving the performance but this is very much dependant on how frequently the data changes, more specifically, you should prune the records where similarity is not in the top 100.

Comment: I already saving only half of the entries where trackID1 is always greater than trackID2. So you mean i should save all combinations even if the table is afterwards twice as big?

Comment: is there a "fast" way to prune the recodrs of a trackID1 in my table without deleting a similarity that maybe in the top100 of trackID2?

Comment: Not really, but if you can be fuzzy about the 'top100' then thresholding the similarity will be quicker.